# Vuejs change data VUEX store state from outside the app

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I have for example an `app.js` with `store.js`. After doing `npm run dev` I am getting a .js which I can include into a page including the `<div>`

Now what I want is to change the `state.baseurl` from outside with javascript like:

```
var options = {
    baseurl:  'http://www.domain.co/'
}
```

Is that possible and how can I achieve that?

App.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue')
import store from './store'
import adrescheck from '../../../../../../../../resources/assets/js/vuecomponenten/components/check'
Vue.component('check', check)
import app from './app.vue'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    render: h => h(app)

});
```

Store.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = {
    state: {
        baseurl: 'http://www.domain.nl/'
    }
}

export default new Vuex.Store(
    store
);
```

Edit:

When i do npm run watch-poll/dev/prod it will generate a .js and wil copy this with webpack to a public folder. From an other domain i want to include this js **AND** want to manipulate the state.baseurl from that domain. So dependency injection.

Comment: Can you further explain the question? From what I see you can easily change the baseurl in the store whenever you want.

Comment: I don't understand your purpose. The goal when you use a store is to have some actions which are update your store

Comment: See my edit, hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly I think the best way to do this would be simply use the [webpack define plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

> Each key passed into DefinePlugin is an identifier or multiple
>   identifiers joined with ..
>
> If the value is a string it will be used as a code fragment. If the
>   value isn't a string, it will be stringified (including functions). If
>   the value is an object all keys are defined the same way. If you
>   prefix typeof to the key, it's only defined for typeof calls. The
>   values will be inlined into the code allowing a minification pass to
>   remove the redundant conditional.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
  VERSION: JSON.stringify('5fa3b9'),
  BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
  TWO: '1+1',
  'typeof window': JSON.stringify('object'),
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
});
```

then in js

```
if (!PRODUCTION) {
  console.log('Debug info');
}

if (PRODUCTION) {
  console.log('Production log');
}
```